# IBD files need to be imported to PHPMyAdmin

Tags: sql, phpmyadmin

What's the easiest way to import several IBD tables to PHPMyAdmin? Would I need to convert them to .sql extensions instead of .ibd? Advice appreciated, as I am not sure if what is said elsewhere is applicable to my case. Thanks